# semantic wiki write to wiki like database

Tags: mediawiki

I'm a newbie in semantic wiki.
I want to do something database and overview computer component for my
organization.

I read about semantic wiki language but cant understand Is I can do like
this in semantic wiki or not. Help me or give me please directions for
find.

For example, I have a HDD.
Each of these have:
- status used or unused
- if used then the computer (parent) or if the unused - storage room
- serial number
- specification
- and etc.

I also have storage room end etc hierarchy.

How can do it in semantic wiki?

Each hdd will have own page?

I found that it can be done by subobject but subobject cant show in are
page.
How I can describe it and do visible it describing or it can be shown
only with ask?
Maybe it can be done by something else subobject?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some answer but it's not that I want. 
Using subobject accept write some data like a page. BUT it cant be present in a page. It can be show only in query. 
It wall be double work for me if I will be the first wrote in object and after show it in some format.

It will be great if I will be can write some data (like the object) and some of wrote data will be show in same page.

it's a pity